# Create JTAppleCalendarView in code

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I want to create and customize a JTAppleCalendarView using only Swif 3 code, i.e. without the Interface Builder, Storyboards or XIB files.

I can create customs labels by code, however when I try to create a JTAppleCalendarView, I simply can not change the frame value, neither the heightAnchor or widthAnchor. This way, my calendar is not displayed.

I am attaching the code of the init of the my custom UIViewController (which implements the Datasource and Delegate protocols):

```
init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)]

    self.view = UIView(frame: frame)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    let margins = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide

    let calendar = JTAppleCalendarView()
    print("CalendarView frame: ", calendar.frame)
    calendar.dataSource = self
    calendar.delegate = self
    calendar.cellInset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    calendar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    calendar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(calendar)
    calendar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor).isActive = true
    calendar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    calendar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    //calendar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    calendar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
}
```

Whenever I change calendar.heightAnchor, calendar.widthAnchor or calendar.frame, I get the error *"Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value."*.

I followed the library tutorial, however they only presents the creation using Interface Builders, which I am not using in my project. Tecnically, the component is just a custom UIView, so I am confused with this error.

Comment: Can you remove the image and add actual code?

Comment: I don't know if I understood what do you mean... I didn't posted any image. I copied the code from xcode and pasted here in the post.

Comment: My bad. For some reason the code appeared as an image earlier :/  ...
Its now selectable again.

Comment: On which line of code are you experiencing the **nil** error? It says that a value is nil. Which value is nil? When the error occurs, you can check to see exactly which value is nil.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am using the Playgrounds, which does not provide this king of debugger. However, I get the _"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil..."_ simply by trying to create a JTAppleCalendarView passing a frame value, as in: _JTAppleCalendarView(frame: frame)_. When I do the same for an UIKit class, such as UIView(frame: frame), it works.

Comment: hmm. This is odd. I thought you might have gotten that error when you set the delegate. On setting of the delegate it automatically calls your delegate function `ConfigureCalendar`. So if you have not setup that function correctly, then maybe something is wrong there? In anycase, if you want to talk more about it then join me here on chat https://gitter.im/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar or open an issue on github. I check my issues every 1 hr or so.

Answer (score 1):

In the code above, I forgot to register the cell.
Solved registering the cell with something like: calendar.registerCellViewClass(type: SomeCellClass.self).

So far, it worked for a simple project. I did not tested with playgrounds.